# unique_ptr operator=

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, smart-pointers

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
ptr = new int[3];                // error
```

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Why this is not compiled? How can I attach native pointer to existing unique_ptr instance?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Firstly, if you need an unique array, make it

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr;
//              ^^^^^
```

This allows the smart pointer to correctly use `delete[]` to deallocate the pointer, and defines the `operator[]` to mimic a normal array.

---

Then, the `operator=` is only defined for rvalue references of unique pointers and not raw pointers, and a raw pointer cannot be implicitly converted to a smart pointer, to avoid accidental assignment that breaks uniqueness. Therefore a raw pointer cannot be directly assigned to it. The correct approach is put it to the constructor:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr (new int[3]);
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or use the `.reset` function:

```
ptr.reset(new int[3]);
// ^^^^^^^          ^
```

or explicitly convert the raw pointer to a unique pointer:

```
ptr = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[3]);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^
```

If you can use C++14, prefer the [`make_unique` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) over using `new` at all:

```
ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(3);
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The reason is that `operator=` doesn't accept `int*` *and* the constructor taking `int*` is marked `explicit` (for both `std::unique_ptr<int>` and `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`). `operator=` being a move assignment operator and not a copy assignment operator has nothing to do with it however.

Comment: @LucDanton: Right. Updated to include that.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer from
[KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393942/1043773)

(since C++11)

```
 tr = (decltype(tr)(new int[3]));
```

Personally I prefer this as it makes updating the type of tr easier. (Only single place to update)

Comment: Won't this call `delete` instead of `delete[]` thus creating undefined behavior?